# Understanding Phase noise of a Hard Limited Sine Wave

Tags: matlab, fft, phase

I need help in understanding the frequency spectrum of a sine wave with phase noise that has been hard limited.

**Background**:
Typically, textbooks define phase noise for a  sinewave, however in many applications, like in the case of a mixer, this sine wave is hard-limited. I am using a simple signum function to convert the sine wave to a square wave, and then am trying to make sense of the spectrum of the hard-limited sine wave having a sinusoidal phase noise.

**Experiment description**:
I have taken a sine wave of frequency 100MHz, sampled at the rate 100GHz. To this sine wave, I have added a sinusoidal phase noise of magnitude "alpha" and frequency 10MHz. When I take the FFT of the resultant signal, I get the expected frequency spectrum.

```
%Code is written in MATLAB
clear all
close all;
f0 = 100e6;
df = 10e6;
tTotal= 1e-6;
Fs = 100e9;
Ts = 1/Fs;
t = 0:Ts:tTotal-Ts;
alpha = 1e-6;
a = sin(2*pi*f0*t + alpha*sin(2*pi*df*t)) ;
afft = fft(a)/length(a);
afftdb = 20*log10(abs(afft)+1e-8);
figure(1)
plot(afftdb);
```

[image: sine wave with sinusoidal phase noise]

The strength of the spur at the bin 111 is 20log(alpha/2) relative to the carrier as expected. Next, I have converted this sine wave into squarewave, then hann-windowed, then low pass filtered and finally I've taken the FFT.

```
asquare = sign(a);
y  = lowpass(asquare,200e6,Fs,'ImpulseResponse','iir','Steepness',0.95);
win = 0.5*(1-cos(2*pi*t/tTotal));
y =y.*win;
%asq_fft = fft(asquare)/length(a);
asq_fft = fft(y)/length(a);
asq_fftdB = 20*log10(abs(asq_fft)+1e-8);
figure(2)
plot(asq_fftdB)
```

I get spur of strength -64dB which is unexpected for me. I didn't expect to get this high spur. I expected the spur to still be 20log(alpha/2) relative to the carrier. I also don't understand why I get so many harmonics too.

[image: FFT of squared sine wave with phase noise]

I also tried changing the value of alpha from 1e-6 to 1e-11. The FFT plot for alpha of 1e-11 is given below:

[image: FFT of squared sine wave with phase noise with alpha of 1e-11]

Still the strength of the spur didn't change. This is surprising to me.
Could anyone please explain why does the spur's strength of -64dB makes sense?

I believe this is not due to folding back of harmonics of square wave, because when I make alpha = 0, I don't see any spurs as shown below.

[image: Pic with alpha = 0]

If I change the offset frequency of the phase noise (df = 7MHz), the spur location change as shown below.

[image]

Comment: It's possible that when you made `alpha=0` you forgot to use `sgn()`, because what I see is the Fourier transform of a square wave, whose harmonics are too high compared to the perturbing signal.